# show TODAY on webpage with Google calendar

Tags: php, html, date, calendar

I want to show only my TODAYS events in my html output.
But with this code it doesnt work for me. If I cancel the line "if ($date = date("Y-m-d")){" the code shows a specific count of events... But how can I create the output for all event on one day only?

```
    if ($date = date("Y-m-d")){

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry){
   $count++;


// Viele weitere Informationen kˆnnen aus dem XML geholt werden wie z.B. $entry->description;
// f¸r die Beschreibung und viele Weitere. Einfach mal das XML-File durchstˆbern.

// Schema f¸r den Google Cal XML Ausgabe laden.
    $ns_gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
    $gCalDate = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)));
    $gCalDateStart = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)));
    $gCalDateEnd = date($dateformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)));
    $gCalStartTime = gmdate($timeformat, strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->startTime)));
    $gCalEndTime = gmdate($timeformat,strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)+date("Z",strtotime($ns_gd->when->attributes()->endTime)));
    $ort=($ns_gd->where->attributes()->valueString);

echo              "Datum: ".$gCalDateStart //Datum
        ."<br/>". "Aufgabe: ".utf8_decode($entry->title) // Titel
        ."<br/>". "Ort: ".$ort // Raum
        ."<br/>". "Beschreibung: ".utf8_decode($entry->content); // Beschreibung

    if($count >=5){ echo "</div> "; break; }else{ echo "<hr>"; }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator in

```
if ($date = date("Y-m-d")){
```

This sets the date. You want to use ==, which compares the values:

```
if ($date == date("Y-m-d")){
```

Comment: But my code doesnt work.. blankscreen ;-(- maybe it is the wrong way? I want to show all events from today, only..hmmmm

Comment: If you're just trying to get get todays events, you don't want to use the if statement at all. You need to adjust $gCalStartTime and gCalEndTime to limit the range from 11:59:59 yesterday until 11:59:59 PM today.

Comment: ahh ok, I remember... there was an info at google api.. Ill try.